# Python: Sort dictionary based on tuple value. List output

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I would like to sort a dictionary based on **one** of the tuple values. Consider the following dictionary example:

```
my_dict = {"apple": (8, 1023), "ant": (3, 29883), "zebra": (4, 489)}
```

Say I would like to sort it based on the first index in the tuple value in the case of the `apple` key it would be the number 8. So I'd expect my output to be

```
["ant", "zebra", "apple"]
```

I know I could use something like

```
 x = sorted(my_dict, key = my_dict.get)
```

But as you can guess, that doesn't work for tuple/list values. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `key=lambda k: my_dict[k][some index]`?

Comment: This code works exactly like you want it to when I run it...

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
>>> my_dict = {"apple": (8, 1023), "ant": (3, 29883), "zebra": (4, 489)}
>>> sorted(my_dict,key=lambda k: my_dict[k][0])
['ant', 'zebra', 'apple']
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you found the answer but the code below will return your dictionary sorted by `tuple[0]`:

```
sorted_dict = []
my_dict = {"apple": (8, 1023), "ant": (3, 29883), "zebra": (4, 489)}
my_dict_copy = sorted(my_dict.items(),key=lambda x: x[1][0])
for i in my_dict_copy:
    sorted_dict.append(i[0])
```